# Linux: How to copy files of a certain length to my home directory

Tags: linux, file-copy

I am trying to copy files of a certain length to my home directory. Is there a command that will do this?

Comment: Are all the files you want to copy in the same directory?

Answer (score 5):

As you tagged the question linux, we may assume that you have the gnu `cp` program.

```
find . -size 300c -type f -exec cp -t "$HOME" {} +
```

will copy all files that are 300 bytes long to your $HOME directory that are under the current dir.

```
find . -size +200c -size -500c -type f -exec cp -t "$HOME" {} +
```

will copy files which are more than 200 and less than 500 bytes long.